# The site description should indicate what Emacs actually is

Tags: discussion

Although [What THE heck are emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77563) may not have been a genuine question, it did make me realise that newcomers to the site aren't told what Emacs is.  As StackExchange sites like to show people activity from elsewhere on the network, it's certainly *possible* that a user might follow a link out of curiosity without knowing in advance what the site is about.

Of course "Emacs" is trivially searchable term at any web search engine; but maybe we could at least link somewhere?

If I open a private browser tab and visit https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ the only explanation given is:

> Emacs Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those using, extending or developing Emacs.

Which doesn't explain anything.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help doesn't help here either.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour (linked from the footer) does slightly better with a variant on the above quote:

> Emacs Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those using, extending, or developing the Emacs text editor.

It seems to me like a mistake that those two quotes are different, and the second version is clearly better.

On the basis that GNU Emacs is not the only Emacs which might be discussed, I'm inclined to suggest we link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs

Comment: +1. Yes, link to Wikipedia. But also provide a short blurb such as the one you quoted or better, which can be found anywhere. E.g., the first line of the Emacs manual: **"Emacs is the extensible, customizable, self-documenting real-time
display editor."** But maybe "text editor" should be used.

Comment: yeah, "self-documenting text editor" would be better.